# Writing an appeal letter for a rejected master programme

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, etiquette

Background:

Due to unexpected factors, I was forced to give up my offer and send applications to find another master programme. As a result, I had to submit my application files at the beginning of May for this programme starting from September of 2023.

This programme was especially suitable for me so after being rejected for the reason of 'Capacity exceeded', I want to write an appeal letter to try my luck.

- What does 'Capacity exceeded' really means? They already have enough candidates confirmed their choice or it is just an polite way to reject?
- What should I include in my letter? The aim seems simple: To get admitted if someone rejects their offer or at least put me in the waiting list.
- Any other general suggestions for writing an appeal letter?

I know the chances are scarce to be admitted. I just want to try as long as it is not regarded as an offensive behavior.

Comment: Have you actually tried inquiring whether they can place you on a waiting list? That would seem like a natural first step.

Comment: To me, an "appeal" suggests that something has gone wrong, some error was made. Do you have reason to think an error was made here, rather than an appropriate rejection? I don't see how you can appeal something without a plan to point to a particular error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that "capacity exceeded" means just what you think it does. All the available slots are full.

There is nothing to appeal. It would not hurt to write saying you are disappointed and would still like to be considered if an opening happens.

Don't expect an answer to that letter.